# Displaying Workbook and Worksheet names in a Listview instead of Listbox

Tags: vba, excel

in WB1, I use the code above to display the opened workbook names in the Lisbox1 and their respective worksheets in listbox2 using a User form. But I would like to use Listview1 and Listview2 instead because I would like for every workbook and Worksheet name to show beside each one of them a checkbox, What changes should I do so it works in Listview1 and Listview2.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Me.Caption = "Workbooks and Sheets Detail"

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        ListBox1.AddItem wb.Name
    Next wb

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim sWorkbookname As String

    sWorkbookname = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
    ListWbWorksheets sWorkbookname

End Sub

Private Sub ListWbWorksheets(ByVal psWorkbookName As String)
    Dim targetWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim n As Long

    Set targetWb = Application.Workbooks(psWorkbookName)
    ListBox2.Clear

    For n = 1 To targetWb.Sheets.Count
        ListBox2.AddItem targetWb.Sheets(n).Name
    Next n

    Set targetWb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It'll take some trial and error to learn how to use a Listview.  This should give you a good start.

[image]

```
Private Sub ListView1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim item As ComctlLib.ListItem
    ListView2.ListItems.Clear

    For Each ws In Workbooks(ListView1.SelectedItem.Text).Worksheets
        Set item = ListView2.ListItems.Add(Text:=ws.Name)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim item As ComctlLib.ListItem

    With ListView1
        .View = lvwReport
        .MultiSelect = False
        .ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Workbooks"
        .ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Paths"
    End With

    With ListView2
        .View = lvwReport
        .MultiSelect = False
        .ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Worksheets"
    End With

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Set item = ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=wb.Name)
        item.SubItems(1) = wb.Path
    Next
End Sub
```